# How to add custom web part into SharePoint Edityourprofile.aspx page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, web-part, aspx

I need to add a custom webpart in SharePoint **edityourprofile.aspx**, I tried by adding the webpart using designer it working for OOTB webparts. But I am unable to add the custom webparts to that page.It's throwing web config error. Please advice me to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

The EditProfile.aspx is an application page. We can only add OOTB web parts into the application page using SharePoint Designer.

You need to create custom user controls for the application pages, register and add user controls to the application pages.

Information about how to create and deploy a user control to an application page:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-custom-user-control-templates-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231548.aspx